# Can "Follow,edit and delete" in record banner of case detail page be hidden using CSS?

Tags: community, napili

[image]

I found in one of the conversation,which is used to hide the "Ask a Question" button in CSS branding editor of Customer community napili template.

.siteforceNapiliFooter #askCommunity { display: none; }

Similarly is there an option to hide "Follow,edit and delete" in record banner of case detail page ?

Comment: Couldn't you simply remove them from the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove those from the Salesforce1 Actions on the Page Layout. That will get rid of them for ya.

Via CSS you can remove the follow by plugging this into the Custom CSS in the branding editor:

```
.not-selected{ visibility: hidden }
```

Comment: Hi Nate, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [answer]. You should [edit] your post with any additional content, not post it in the comments.

Comment: @Nate Hembree : Actually those button are aura components and so not possible to track their id's to hide them.. so how did u actually find this ".not-selected{visibility : hidden}" ? please let us know so that it will be very helpul in finding for some more buttons...

Comment: I inspected the element in Chrome and isolated the specific class for the Follow button class, which luckily for us is unique for the Follow button. There are other things you can play around with as well - I've messed around with the search bar and nav bar this way too.